Choice of norm and conditions on $G(\theta)$ to ensure bounded eigenvalues in an integral operator
I am an engineering student working on a nonlinear eigenvalue problem that needs functional analysis-problem. Here, the goal is to prove that there are a finite amount of eigenvalues in the right-half plane $Re(\lambda) \geq 0$ by finding a bound on the norm of eigenvalues in this plane.
$(\lambda I_n - \int_{-\tau}^{0} G(\theta)e^{\lambda \theta}d\theta)v=0$
In the past, I only had limited functional analysis. The idea is to show that for every $Re(\lambda) \geq 0$ there only should be a finite amount of eigenvalues (multiplicity included) in the right-half complex plane for the square matrix $\int_{-\tau}^{0} G(\theta)e^{\lambda \theta}d\theta$ where $G(\theta)$ is a matrix-function with a mapping from $[-\tau,0]$ to $\mathbb{R} ^{n\times n}$. The most logical thing to do is the following:
$|\lambda| \leq \int_{-\tau}^{0} ||G(\theta)|| \,\,|e^{\lambda \, \theta}| \,d\theta$
$|\lambda| \leq \int_{-\tau}^{0} ||G(\theta)|| \,\,|e^{\lambda \, \theta}| \,d\theta = \int_{-\tau}^{0} ||G(\theta)|| \,\,|e^{Re(\lambda)\, \theta}| \,d\theta$
Hence, since $|e^{Re(\lambda)\, \theta}|\leq 1$ this value will always be bounded. For a given right-half plane $Re(\lambda) \geq r$ there will always be a finite amount of eigenvalues to be found in this plane.
As clearly can be seen, I am not sure how to choose the norms as there exist different matrix norms. Another question is how to put constraints on $G(\theta)$ (e.g., smoothness, boundedness) in order to make sure that the norm will still remain bounded. It seems logical that for a pathological choice of $G(\theta)$ the eigenvalues still could expand unboundedly in the right-half complex plane.

If the integral exists, the result of the integral is just an $n \times n$ matrix, so it should have $n$ eigenvalues. What am I missing?

You are correct, I made a mistake in my earlier question. Now it should be ok. For further questions, do not hesitate to comment.

"Here, the goal is to prove that there are a finite amount of eigenvalues in the right-half plane Re(λ)≥0 by finding a bound on the norm of eigenvalues in this plane." How this would guarantee the finiteness of the number of eigenvalues?
